# How to get the name and tag of button in function?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have created some buttons in loop and I want to get the name and tag of that button which is tapped.I have set the property name in loop so how can I get the name and tag in function selectCurrentColor

This is my code:

```
for i=1,16 do
    coloringSelect[i]=display.newImage("Resources/coloring_01/color" .. i .. ".png")
    print("color" .. i .. ".png")
    coloringSelect[i]:scale(0.28,0.28)
    coloringSelect[i].x=colorx
    coloringSelect[i].y=colory
    coloringSelect[i].name= "color"..i
    coloringSelect[i].tag= i


    if i%2==0 then

        colorx=40
        colory=colory+30
    else
        colorx=colorx+38
    end
    stageGroup:insert( coloringSelect[i])
    coloringSelect[i]:addEventListener("tap",selectCurrentColor)
end



function selectCurrentColor(self,event)
    print(event.tag)
    print(self.name)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function selectCurrentColor(event)
    print(event.target.tag)
    print(event.target.name)
end
```